# Ошибка ninja: error: в C

Tags: c, ide, clion, jetbrains

Начал учить язык C. Как IDE используб Clion. Создал C Sourse File. Написал вот-такой вот hello world:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Вместо "Hello, World!" получаю ошибку:

```
ninja: error: unknown target 'c', did you mean 'all'?
```

Подскажите, что делать?

Comment: видимо создался кривой файл ninja. Почему - а кто его знает. я бы в консоли собирал и не переживал. А IDE - это на будущее.

Comment: показывайте свой CMakeLists.txt